# Como manejar excepciones de BD en EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Tengo este código que intenta guardar el modelo en la base de datos y hace dos catch uno para las validaciones de EF y el otro genérico.
No me da ningún error del primer catch pero en el segundo me da un error de una clave foranea creo , pero no veo como resolverlo.

```
 try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }


        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            // Retrieve the error messages as a list of strings.
            var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
                    .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
                    .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);

            // Join the list to a single string.
            var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);

            // Combine the original exception message with the new one.
            var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);

            string error = exceptionMessage;


            // Throw a new DbEntityValidationException with the improved exception message.
            throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error2 = ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message;
        }
```

El error que recibo es

> Instrucción INSERT en conflicto con la restricción FOREIGN KEY "FK_VentasLinias_Articulos". El conflicto ha aparecido en la base de datos "testweb", tabla "dbo.Articulos".
>   Se terminó la instrucción.

Unas capturas de la relación que tengo definida en el diagrama de la BD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias,

Comment: No se muy bien cual es tu pregunta. El error parece claro, alguno de los valores que estás metiendo en las columnas con FK no existen en la tabla  articulos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagino que no será pero los datos que metes en las claves foraneas existen en la tabla artículos previamente?

Comment: Yo creo que si... por eso no se si hay alguna forma de capturar lo que haria el "insert" y hacerlo yo manualmente. Gracias

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/46108)

Comment: @ilernet ¿Por qué la marcaste como aceptada? ¿Eso resolvió tu problema? No veo ninguna explicación.

Comment: Efectivamente tienes razón @JuankGlezz. Ahora elimino la respuesta.

Comment: Vale no puedo borrarlo al estar aceptada. Si es un problema que algún moderador la elimine. Gracias

Comment: si , la respuesta me sirve. Gracias